# Android: Check for first time launch

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I made a **Shared Preferences system** that will check if the user launches the app for the first time, if so, it will launch a **AlertDialog**

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    // Make MenuInflater
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
    if ( firstRun )
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
        ad.setTitle("Nieuwe gebruiker?");  
        ad.setMessage("- Als u naar de volgende dag wilt kun u de knop morgen gebruik in het menu.\n - In het menu kunt u ook terug naar vandaag en u kunt de pagina refreshen. \n - U kunt zelfs de roosterwijzigingen delen via WhatsApp of via E-Mail.");   
        ad.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
             dialog.dismiss(); 
        }  
        });  
        ad.show();
    }
// Return True
return true;
}
```

But I didnt make it good I think, because **it launches the AlertDialog everytime you start the app**. What did I wrong and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
....
boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
if ( firstRun ){
  settings.edit().putBoolean("firstRun", false).commit(); //set your flag to false
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't changing the value of the `firstRun` in the SharedPreferences to false after you've shown the dialog.

In your AlertDialog's OK button, save `firstRun` in SharedPreferences to have the value of `false`, so that the if statement is not triggered again.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar and I solved it by creating a sqlite database in which when the app is first time opened I check if the database table is empty if it is I do something and insert data to database if there is data in database I do nothing .